# Testing Azure Function With Local Url Error

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I am building an Azure function and just updated to latest everything, this is my code:

```
  log.Info($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");

  var localCall = httpClient.GetAsync(urls[EnvironmentNames.LOCAL]);
  var localCallResult = await localCall;

  log.Info($"{EnvironmentNames.LOCAL} call status code {localCallResult.StatusCode}");
```

The url is:

`{EnvironmentNames.LOCAL, $"local.mysite.net:5050/doThings"},`

I am getting the following error when testing locally in Visual Studio:

> System.ArgumentException: Only 'http' and 'https' schemes are allowed.
>
> Parameter name: requestUri

Can I not test Azure calls locally?

Comment: Any progress? If the solution works could you accept it to close your question?Otherwise just let us know where you are trapped.

Comment: @JerryLiu Accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `urls[EnvironmentNames.LOCAL]` has a complete url value like `http://local.mysite.net:5050/doThings`. The protocol `http://` or `https://` can't be omitted as `httpClient` won't add it for us.